# Reduce "Synchronizing Object" time for Tree Curve

Tags: cycles-render-engine, sapling-addon

I've set up a sapling curve using the tree add on. I've left it as an animated curve. When I go to render in cycles, the rest of the scene Synchronizes fine, but then I get stuck with the message "Synchronizing Object | tree" for a VERY long time before rendering takes place. Would this change if I turned the curve into a mesh? Would doing so screw up the animation?

Comment: Does your tree have a lot of leaves? If so that might be slowing down the synchronization process. By converting to mesh you could use particle instances for the leaves instead and save some memory/time, however the conversion to mesh might kill your animation, depending on how you made it, which you never explain how.

Comment: I used the built in animation tools inside of the sapling generator.

Comment: As far as I remember those are armature animations and must be used with mesh objects only if I'm not mistaken, so might have to convert to mesh anyways. Also check your curve resolution and bevel resolution, see if they are not too high, creating too dense meshes. You can always convert to mesh only a copy of your objects, saving the original if something goes wrong